# Show that the space $C^{0, \gamma}(U)$ is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

How can we show that the space $C^{0, \gamma}(U)$ is complete??

I have tried the following:

So that the space is complete, the following has to stand:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_0 \text{ such that } m, n \geq n_0 : ||u_m-u_n||_{C^{0, \gamma}} <\epsilon$$

We have that $$||u||_{C^{0, \gamma}}=||u||_{C(U)}+[u]_{C^{0, \gamma}}$$ where $$||u||_{C(U)}:=\sup_{x \in U} |u(x)| \\  [u]_{C^{0, \gamma}}(U)=\sup_{x, y \in U , x \neq y} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}}$$

So, we have the following:

$$||u_m-u_n||_{C^{0, \gamma}}=||u_m-u_n||_{C(U)}+[u_m-u_n]_{C^{0, \gamma}} \\ =\sup_{x \in U} |(u_m-u_n)(x)|+\sup_{x, y \in U , x \neq y} \frac{|(u_m-u_n)(x)-(u_m-u_n)(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}} $$

How could we continue??

Comment: But in this case we want to show that the space is complete... @Martingalo

Comment: All your last 10 questions (not to go too far in the past) received an upvoted answer, none of them got accepted. Would you mind either accepting them or let the answerers know how they can improve on their work? Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [proving facts about $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157972/proving-facts-about-alpha-h%c3%b6lder-continuous-functions)

Comment: She has 307 questions, 53% accept rate @GiovanniDeGaetano